Expected number of pairs of waves

There are 9 people standing in a circle. Each person waves at $3$ distinct random people. No one can wave to themself. What is the expected number of pairs of individuals who wave at each other?

Is the answer $\frac{9C_3}{3} = 28$? Since $9$ people wave to $3$ distinct people, $9C_3$, and we overcount cases, therefore divide by $3$.

See Linearity of Expectation,
which includes a proof that the formula applies even when the events are not
independent of each other.
Assume, for illustrative purposes that Person-1 waves to each of Person-2, Person-3, Person-4.
Since Person-2 waves to three different people, the probability that Person-1 is included is $~3/8.~$
Therefore, the expected number of mutual waves for Person-1 is
$$3 \times 3/8 = 9/8.$$
Therefore, the total number of expected mutual waves for all people is
$$9 \times 9/8 = 81/8.$$
However, each pair of individuals who wave at each other generate two mutual waves.
Therefore, the expected number of pairs of individuals is
$$( ~81/8 ~) \div 2.$$

$\underline{\text{Addendum}}$
The analysis in the comment of Paul is worth highjacking, as a more elegant solution.  Note: for some reason, that comment was subsequently deleted.
There are $~\displaystyle \binom{9}{2}~$ pairs of people, and each pair of people has a $~\displaystyle \left( ~\frac{3}{8} ~\right)^2~$ probability of waving to each other.
Therefore, the computation is
$$\binom{9}{2} \times  \left( ~\frac{3}{8} ~\right)^2.$$

@lulu Agreed; answer edited.

"Since Person-2 waves to three different people, the probability that Person-1 is included is $3/8.$ "
Can you tell me why the probability of Person-2 waving to Person-1 is 3/8 and not 1/8?

@ShsTht Because Person-2 is selecting $~3~$ different people from the group of Person-1, Person-3, Person-4, ..., Person-9.  The probability that Person-1 is one of the three people selected is $~\displaystyle \frac{3}{8}.~$
